# Display Gridview Tables based on dropdown value selection using asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, inner-join, aspxgridview

> I have a dropdown value which selects **customer name** and also i have a
>   **sales executive** dropdown which selects executives name i want to
>   display **Gridview table** based on **customer name** selection but i am able
>   to display only its **ID** . i need to display their **names** instead of **ID**.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" runat="server" Text="Customer Name"></asp:Label>
         <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <asp:DropDownList ID="customerDetails" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" CssClass="mydropdownlist">
               <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Value="0">--Select Customer--</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
     </div>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
     <asp:Label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" runat="server" Text="Sales Executive"></asp:Label>
       <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="salesExceutive" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" CssClass="mydropdownlist">
                 <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Value="0">--Select Sales Executive--</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
       </div>
   </div>

<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary"
         runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
```

I have tried following.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (customerText != "0" && salesExeText == "0")
        {

        string sqlQuery = @"SELECT * from app_order_master where 
                              customer_id = " + customerText ;

        using (DataTable dt = SMSDBHelperFE.ExecuteReaderDataTable(CommandType.Text, sqlQuery, null))
        {

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();                    
        }
      }
    }
```

[image]

See the picture above instead of id i need to display name

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not fully understandable. But I think you are storing Customer Id in the table. And while retrieving data from  **app_order_master** table and binding with gridview you are not Joining it with Customer table with the id. That's why you are not getting Customer name.As I don't know your table structure I couldn't help much.But you can self learn about joining from below link

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins